# Is there a way to pull/get a list of projects from TortoiseSVN programmatically?

Tags: version-control, tortoisesvn, svn-api

I have looked into TortoiseSVN documentation and have not found anything if even possible but I thought I throw the question out there. Can you programmatically pull/get a list of projects from a svn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, yes you can in two ways.

- Since TorroiseSVN is just a UI client for subversion, you need to start svn as a process with some parameter like e.g.: svn list --verbose.

On Windows looks like:

```
ShellExecute(0, 0, L"svn list --verbose", 0, 0 , SW_SHOW );
```

Take a look at the APIs for svn as well: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.developer.usingapi.html

- And here you have the APIs (automatisation) for TortoiseSVN directly: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html , e.g.

> Examples (which should be entered on one line):
>
> TortoiseProc.exe /command:commit
>                    /path:"c:\svn_wc\file1.txt*c:\svn_wc\file2.txt"
>                    /logmsg:"test log message" /closeonend:0
>
> TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"c:\svn_wc\" /closeonend:0
>
> TortoiseProc.exe /command:log /path:"c:\svn_wc\file1.txt"
>                    /startrev:50 /endrev:60 /closeonend:0

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseSVN is not meant to be used in this way - it's a GUI client, a Windows Explorer shell extension. If you need to automate things with Subversion, use `svn.exe` (installed with TSVN as of 1.7, or you can get it elsewhere), a library like [SharpSVN](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/), or the TSVN DLLs directly (probably the least-desirable approach)

However, keep in mind that Subversion has no notion of "projects" - it's just a versioned directory structure. You apply meaning to the structure that you create within the repository.